# advanced projection query

Tags: c#, linq

Any better way of doing this

```
using (var db = new SmartContext())
{
    var MyQuery = from idr in db.ID_SB
                  join tk in db.Track_SB on idr.MB_Track_ID equals tk.MB_TrackID
                  join talr in db.Track_Album_Reln on tk.MB_TrackID equals talr.MB_Track_ID
                  join tal in db.Album_SB on talr.MB_AlbumID equals tal.MB_Release_ID
                  orderby idr.Last_played descending
                  select new
                  {
                      mb = tk.MB_TrackID,
                      Hash = idr.Hash,
                      Title = tk.Title,
                      Album = tal.Album_Name,

                      Times_Played = idr.Times_played,
                      Last_Played = idr.Last_played

                  };

    string artist = "";
    var list = new[] { new {  Hash = "", Title = "", Album = "", Artist = "", Times_Played = "", Last_Played = ""}}.ToList();
    list.Clear();
    foreach (var q in MyQuery)
    {
        int i = 0;
        var art = db.Track_Artist_Reln.Where(a => a.MB_Track_ID == q.mb);
        foreach (var a in art)
        {
            var tart = db.Artist_SB.Where(ar => ar.MB_Artist_ID == a.MB_ArtistID).Select(ar => ar.Artist_Name);
            foreach (var tar in tart)
            { if (i != 0) { artist = artist + ", " + tar; } else { artist = tar; i++; } }
        }
        list.Add(new
        {
            Hash = q.Hash.ToString(),
            Title = q.Title.ToString(),
            Album = q.Album.ToString(),
            Artist = artist.ToString(),
            Times_Played = q.Times_Played.ToString(),
            Last_Played = q.Last_Played.ToString(),            
          });
    }


    ListView1.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

is there any better way for this as it  is consuming lot of time

this code serves the purpose

in this i want to retrieve

- hash
- Title
- Albumname
- Artist ( containing all the artist for that song in single row field artist)
- Times played
- Last played

everything i am able to get just by getting join of everything apart from artist name

there are many to may relations
main tables ID_SB, Track_SB, Album_SB, Artist_SB
other are relationship storing the primary keys of both tables

Comment: One quick thing to improve it, move the nested db queries in the two foreach loops in to the main query by having it returned as a collections in your first query. This will cause it to have a LOT fewer trips to the db.

Comment: You should get rid of the *_Reln tables too while at it, EF has directly supported many-to-many relationships for many years now.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop can be replaced with using `string.Join(…)` and `.SelectMany()` to flatten the nested list (really `IEnumerable`) into one:

```
var artist = string.Join(", ",
                         db.Track_Artist_Reln
                           .Where(a => a.MB_Track_ID == q.mb)
                           .SelectMany(a => db.Artist_SB
                                              .Where(ar => ar.MB_Artist_ID == a.MB_ArtistID)
                                              .Select(ar => ar.Artist_Name)));
```

Instead of converting the enumerable to a List manually you can use `.ToList()`:

```
var list = MyQuery.Select(q => new{
        Hash = q.Hash.ToString(),
        Title = q.Title.ToString(),
        Album = q.Album.ToString(),
        Artist = string.Join(", ",
                             db.Track_Artist_Reln
                               .Where(a => a.MB_Track_ID == q.mb)
                               .SelectMany(a => db.Artist_SB
                                                  .Where(ar => ar.MB_Artist_ID == a.MB_ArtistID)
                                                  .Select(ar => ar.Artist_Name))),
        Times_Played = q.Times_Played.ToString(),
        Last_Played = q.Last_Played.ToString(),            
        }.ToList();
```